# SAP B1 studio for ms visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, sapb1

How can install the SAP Business One Add-On Project template in Visual Studio 2019?

I need to build a Add-On with C# but I don't know how to the templates or witch king of c# project use for that.

Comment: Which SAP B1 version are you using?

Comment: Hi Kinyanjui Kamau, I am using the 9.3

Comment: 9.3 should be ok. Thing is, I had to downgrade to VS 2017 for the SAP addon templates to show/work.

Comment: Hi Kinyanjui Kamau, I did the downgrade to VS 2017 but can't find the templates. 
Do I need to install anything else?

Comment: Hi, I installed B1DE 2.2 and that inserted the templates into VS 2017.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Create a new SAP B1 Add-on with 2019]

now it is available for 2019 also

Answer (score 0):

It's ready for Visual Studio 2022 now. Here are the project templates:

[image: Screenshot of “Add a new project” screen]

Answer (score -1):

you can use vs2013, you don't need vs2019 for development

Answer (score -1):

you need to install SAPB1 Studio, once it's installed. SAP SDK will be available in visual Studio.  there is a sequence of installation:  Visual Studio 2019->SAPB1 version 9 ( or v10) -> SAP DIAPI ->SAP B1 Studio.